# Creating a chrome extension to dowload images

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have some images on a website that I want to download. However they are blob images and I can't download them because my requests always get rejected (maybe I am missing a header or a payload idk since devtools dont show me). When I open devtools and look at the network traffic I can see the requst and I can get a preview of the image. I can even download that one, but I want to automate. I decided to write my own chrome extension using the devtools api to capture the responses and I am able to retrieve the blob image, however unlike in the regular devtools network tab, my blob is still fully encrypted. I want to know how I can achieve the same with my extension.

## My Setup

manifest.json

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Sniffer",
    "description": "Base Level Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
    "permissions": [
      "tabs"
    ],
    "icons": {
      "100": "juste.png"
    }
  }
```

devtools.html

```html
<script src="devtools.js"></script>
```

devtools.js

```js
chrome.devtools.panels.create("MyPanel", null, 'panel.html');
```

panel.html

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="a"></div>
        <script src="panel.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

panel.js  (edited)

```js
let a = document.getElementById('a');

chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(request => {
  request.getContent((body) => {
    if (request.request && request.request.url) {
      if (request.request.url.includes('blob')) {
        let a = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.style = "display: none";
        let json = atob(body);
            blob = new Blob([json], {type: "text/plain"}),
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = "fileName.png";
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

## Output  (edited)

I've reworked the decrypting process of the blob. I'm now using atob to  decrypt the blob and save it as a png. When I open the working png and my downloaded in a text editor I can see that it's almost properly decoded, however it seems like the encoding is worng, it seems like I have to save it in ansi instead of utf-8 or whatever atob is returning, since the original png also is in ansi format.

Comment: As the documentation says it's base64 encoded. See examples for decoding it into the format you want.

Comment: I tried base64 but compared to the actually decrypted blob its not 100% matching, when I manually decode with bsse64 it just gets some parts right

Comment: You're not decoding it correctly. Look for examples that do it via Uint8Array.